# python: using attributes as an enum, and then assigning the attributes to another class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following two classes :

```
class DbQuery:
    def __init__(self,query):
        self.query = query

class DbResultSet:
    def __init__(self,query):
        self.result = []
```

And these classes are used for SQL queries and results, attributes are used to simulate enum-like functionality. A query looks as follows :

```
q_forum_heirarchy =\
    type(   "RtDbQuery",
            DbQuery( """SELECT level, id, parent_id, name 
                        FROM forum_heirarchy_node
                        WHERE forum_id = :f_id 
                        AND level != 0
                        ORDER BY level ASC;"""), 
            LEVEL=0, ID=1, PARENT_ID=2, NAME=3 )
```

Is there some way for me to copy the attributes from DbQuery into DbResultset ? I don't want to have to embed the query in the resultset because then I would have to write `db_resultset.query.LEVEL` instead of db_resultset.LEVEL to get to the enum ordinals.

I see a `__get_attribute__` method but I suppose this is indexed by attribute_name.

**edit**:

The code is invalid python, it doesn't change the gist of what I was asking. I discovered psycopg2(database library) can do namedtuples() (python objects with the performance characters of enums), so I can't be bothered to update it :D

Comment: You mean some sort of attribute proxy? Something like this maybe? http://code.activestate.com/recipes/510402-attribute-proxy-forwarding-attribute-access/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should use `__getattr__` method. This method is used by lookup mechanism when no class attributes are found.

```
class DbQuery(object):
  def __init__(self,query):
        self.query = query

class DbResultSet(object):
  def __init__(self, dbquery):
        self.result = []
        self.dbquery = dbquery
  def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.dbquery,name)
```

Comment: bingo ! I knew it would be something simple like this <3.